# When using get_terms with hide_empty = true, terms that only contain scheduled posts are not returned. How to override this?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms, post-status, scheduled-posts

My code is simply:

```
$cats = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
    ],
);
```

Obviously, `hide_empty` is `true` by default. There's a category that only contains scheduled posts and it's not being returned; I want to override this behavior. Somewhere in the code the value of `post_status` is involved, but I searched the source of `WP_Term_Query` and found nothing. Is there a filter that can be used to override this, or do I have to write my own SQL query?